# How to assign custom color to masked cells in seaborn heatmap?

Tags: python, seaborn, heatmap

I have a dataset with values -4 to 4 and some nan values. I plot the heatmap using seaborn heatmap. Colormap I need to use is from red to white to blue. My problem is masked cells are also white/greyish which is hard to differentiate then values close to 0 in colormap.

Is there any way to assign nan values as black without plotting the heatmap twice?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have two options.

1. Use the `bad` value of the colormap. I.e. if masked values are set to `nan`, they would be shown in the color set to the colormap via

   ```
   colormap.set_bad("black")
   ```
2. Make the background of the axes black, such that values which are masked and hence not plotted appear as transparent with the background color see through,

   ```
   ax.set_facecolor("black")
   ```

Answer (score 1):

- `.cm.get_cmap` was deprecated in `matplotlib 3.7`

  - Use `mpl.colormaps['viridis']` or `mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')` instead.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl

np.random.seed(2023)
matrix = np.random.random_sample(size=(10, 10)) - 0.5

mask = np.where(np.logical_or(matrix >= 0.2, matrix <= -0.2), True, False)

cmap = mpl.colormaps.get_cmap('viridis')
cmap.set_bad("k")

sns.heatmap(matrix, cmap=cmap, mask=mask)
```

[image]

---

Here is a full example:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sns
cmap = mpl.cm.get_cmap('gray_r')
cmap.set_bad("white")
sns.heatmap(..., cmap=cmap)
```